Google Classroom API Assign Coursework To Students
I'm trying to create a script that will assign students by ID to coursework. The code appears to be working, but I'm getting a 500 response from the server. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I've tried different student ids and they all give the same result?
assign_coursework_to_students(service, course_id, coursework_id, student_ids_to_add):
    """Assign coursework to specific individual students with retry on internal error."""
    print(student_ids_to_add)
    for attempt in range(3):  # Retry up to 3 times
        try:
            # Prepare the request body
            body = {
                "assigneeMode": "INDIVIDUAL_STUDENTS",
                "modifyIndividualStudentsOptions": {
                    "addStudentIds": student_ids_to_add
                }
            }

            # Make the API call to modify assignees
            response = service.courses().courseWork().modifyAssignees(
                courseId=course_id,
                id=coursework_id,
                body=body
            ).execute()
            print(f"Successfully assigned coursework to students: {response['title']} (ID: {response['id']})")
            return  # Exit the function on success

        except HttpError as error:
            print(f"An error occurred: {error.resp.status} - {error._get_reason()}")

            if error.resp.status == 500:
                print(f"Internal error encountered. Retrying... (Attempt {attempt + 1})")
                time.sleep(2)  # Wait before retrying
                continue  # Retry the request
            else:
                print(f"An error occurred while assigning coursework: {error}")
                return  # Exit on non-500 error
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An unexpected error occurred: {e}")
            return  # Exit on unexpected errors


Can you provide your complete code?

500 errors are pretty hard to debug client side. Your code seems fine to me. I would encourage you to file a bug in the public issue tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191645&template=823907
